# update error and rollback transaction

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables ticket_addresses,tickets,['2014nosec add']. I want to update this ticket_addresses table but unfortunately i have run this query and it updated the  entire table where the column ta_address_2  with '.'.
my doubt is my query is wrong because the from table ['2014nosec add']  is different from the update table  and it does not have ta-address-2 column  on it should give me  an error because the from table is not the in the list.
is there any way to rollback the update query as i have not used it as transaction . I am using sql server managament studio.

```
update 
ticket_addresses set ta_address_2 = '.'  
FROM  ['2014nosec add'] inner join tickets ------> I think this is wrong here.. it should be ticket_addresses table(right) 
  on  ['2014nosec add'].[PCN] = tickets.t_reference  
   where ta_address_2 = '' 
and ta_address_1 <> ' ' and  t_camera_ticket = '-1'
  and 
convert (datetime,t_date_time_issued,101) between convert(datetime,'2014/04/15',101) and convert (datetime,'2014/06/06',101)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default SQL Server using ["Autocommit"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) mode for transaction management. So you can't rollback this query because it already commited.